# If all the diagonal blocks are not of the same order then all the eigenvalues are not an integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1\\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &1\\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &1\\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &0\\
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0_{2\times2} & 1_{2\times3} & 1_{2\times2}&1_{2\times1}\\
 1_{3\times2} & 0_{3\times3} & 1_{3\times2}&1_{3\times1}  \\
 1_{2\times2} & 1_{2\times3} & 0_{2\times2}&1_{2\times1}  \\
 1_{1\times2} & 1_{1\times3} & 1_{1\times2}&0_{1\times1}  \\
  \end{array}
\end{pmatrix}$ 
be a symmetric matrix whose entries are blocks(diagonal blocks entry must be zero and non-diagonal blocks entry must be one). 
 How to prove/disprove that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are not integer if and only if the diagonal blocks are not of the same order.
Note that the number of diagonal blocks $\geq 3$ and order of diagonal blocks$\geq 1$ .

Comment: You basically have a sequence of positive integers $(n_1,\dots,n_p)$ (here $(2,3,2,1)$) defining the matrix as blocks $n_i\times n_i$ of zeroes on the diagonal, and every other coefficients equal to $1$. Do you want to prove that $M$ has integer eigenvalues iff  $n_1=\cdots=n_p$ ?